# "A refresh_token is not available (RuntimeError)" when authenticating with Facebook or Google+

Tags: devise, oauth-2.0, cucumber, google-oauth, facebook-oauth

Using `omniauth-oauth2` alongside `omniauth-facebook` and `omniauth-google-oauth2` for social authentication with Devise, we saw this obscure error cropping up in our Cucumber suite. We couldn't figure out what was going wrong. Google led us on some goose hunts. Any ideas?

```
  @selenium
  Scenario: I can login with Google+             # features/authentication.feature:114
 A refresh_token is not available (RuntimeError)
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/oauth2-0.8.1/lib/oauth2/access_token.rb:81:in `refresh!'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/omniauth-oauth2-1.0.3/lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth2.rb:63:in `callback_phase'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/omniauth-1.1.1/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:219:in `callback_call'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/omniauth-1.1.1/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:175:in `call!'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/omniauth-1.1.1/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:157:in `call'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/omniauth-1.1.1/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:177:in `call!'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/omniauth-1.1.1/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:157:in `call'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/meta_request-0.2.1/lib/meta_request/middlewares/app_request_handler.rb:11:in `call'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/rack-contrib-1.1.0/lib/rack/contrib/response_headers.rb:17:in `call'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/meta_request-0.2.1/lib/meta_request/middlewares/headers.rb:16:in `call'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/meta_request-0.2.1/lib/meta_request/middlewares/meta_request_handler.rb:13:in `call'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/request_store-1.0.5/lib/request_store/middleware.rb:9:in `call'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/plugin/rack.rb:54:in `call'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/warden-1.2.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/warden-1.2.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/warden-1.2.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__3252172032061673430__call__1496937490684777386__callbacks'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/bugsnag-1.2.12/lib/bugsnag/rack.rb:36:in `call'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/cucumber-rails-1.4.0/lib/cucumber/rails/action_controller.rb:10:in `call'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:134:in `call'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:64:in `block in call'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:49:in `each'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:49:in `call'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/capybara-2.0.3/lib/capybara/server.rb:19:in `call'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
 /Users/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
    Given I am a visitor                          # features/step_definitions/authentication_steps.rb:6
    When I visit the login or register page       # features/step_definitions/authentication_steps.rb:52
    And I login with Google+                      # features/step_definitions/authentication_steps.rb:29
    Then I see the text "Signed in successfully." # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:159
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We discovered that the error only occurred when a previous test ran that used `Timecop` to travel forward in time by 1 day. As it turns out, Google tokens only last for 3600 seconds, so travelling an hour ahead invalidated the original token. Refreshing was then made impossible.

Moral of the story: don't forget to `Timecop.return` after travelling in time.